# UnityContainerExtension examples

Tags: .net, unity-container

Are there any good `UnityContainerExtension` examples/tutorials out there?

Please do not refer to the *Unity Event Broker* example.

Comment: Could you explain what's missing out of the event broker sample? I don't know of any other specific "this is an example" out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another example : http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/09/custom-object-factory-unity-extension.html
and here http://www.agileatwork.com/auto-mocking-unity-container-extension/

Answer (score 2):

I found this:
http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/building-a-unity-extension-for-entity-framework-poco-configuration-repository-and-unit-of-work/

But it did not get me going using the UnityContainerExtension... So I don't know how good of an example it is.